# Unix zip command is updating existing archive instead of creating a new one

Tags: shell, zip

```
$(which zip) -r ../data.zip .
```

The contents of the folders are changing dynamically overtime, I tested it first with including `huge.pdf` file and later deleted it, but still `data.zip` stays the same size. On unzipping I could see the `huge.pdf` file there.

I wish that zip command overrides the existing archive completely.

and I'm executing this shell command in an application (nodejs)

Edit: I don't think so the linked question is duplicate.

Comment: @ThomasDickey will -u flag remove file automatically from the archive if it has been deleted from the folder?

Comment: The point of the duplicate is that someone with the same problem (phrased differently) found the answer in the manual page.

Comment: actually it turns out to be that I need the -FS flag (file sync) http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First note that executing `zip` through `$(which zip)` is the same as executing it as just `zip`.  The `which` utility locates a program file in the user's path.

Given an existing Zip archive, `zip` will *add* new files, *replace* existing files, but it will not *delete* files in the archive if those files have been removed from the file system.

To delete a file from a Zip archive:

```
$ zip -d archive.zip filename
```

You may obviously also just remove the archive with `rm` before re-creating it.

For your NodeJS script, you could use

```
rm -f ../data.zip && zip -r ../data.zip .
```

The `-f` flag to `rm` makes `rm` not fail if the archive does not exist.

Comment: for the $(which zip) part, can I work with just `zip` without path? is it always available on different server environments?

Comment: so `zip` will add the files if an archive already exists at the destination? so you suggest appending `rm ../data.zip`? I can't really apply -d for each file because I don't care about the diff in the contents.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include the file deletion, and creation of zip in a single line command?

Comment: @user2727195 Yes, `which zip` searches your path for `zip` and returns the found location.  This is the location that would be picked if `zip` mas used without a specific path.

Comment: @user2727195 You could use `rm -f ../data.zip && zip -r ../data.zip .`.

Comment: what is the -f flag for?, also if archive doesn't exists, will it still work?

Comment: @user2727195 The `-f` flag for `rm` makes it not fail if the file does not exist.

Comment: @user2727195 Sorry for not mentioning the `-FS` flag. It's listed as "a new mode" so I thought you'd be happier with a solution that would not depend on the version of `zip`...

Comment: how new that'd be, would I run into problem with deployment of code on different server environments?

Comment: @Kusalananda `rm -f something` always returns true, so instead of a `&&` a `;` would be sufficient. You just reduced the keyboard's MTBF by 50% :-)

Comment: @ott-- A `;` would be sufficient. I used `&&` out of habit. I do `cmd1 && cmd2` a lot.

Comment: @user2727195 I'm really not sure, but the answer to the question that Thomas Dickey is linking to says that it's available in version 3.0.

Comment: @user2727195 `$(which zip)` can, in some unusual circumstances that can happen due to how the system is installed (`zip` is in a directory name containing special characters, or `which` command not available), fail to invoke `zip` when a plain `zip` would work. It would never succeed when a plain `zip` would fail, except in unusual circumstances that you'd have to force in the script (bypass a function or alias called `zip`, for which `command zip` is the right solution — but this isn't necessary in any sane situation). Never use `$(which zip)`: it can't possibly help and can definitely hurt.

Comment: @ott About your (now old) comment about replacing `&&` with `;`... `rm -f` would still fail if the Zip file could not be removed due to permission problems.  I would still leave `&&` there so that `zip` is not executed if this happens.

Answer (score 1):

As it states the `zip` command's help entry:

> The default action is to **add or replace** zipfile entries from list

This explains why the default behavior does not involve deleting files in the zipfile, and the reason why `huge.pdf` remains in it.

If you want to override the existing archive completely, you could create a new temporary zipfile and then replace the previous one. Also, the `which` command invocation does not appear to be necessary, so the command should be the following:

```
zip -r temp.zip . ; mv temp.zip ../data.zip
```

Comment: Simpler solution is to zip to stdout and redirect to file:  `zip - . > ../data.zip`

Comment: @boyvinall Maybe it worth to make an answer from your comment, since the solution is the most elegant